# Variable doesn't change with if statement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm facing an issue with Java Script. 
I have a piece of code that creates rain inside a div and I need this rain to turn off and on according to my if statements.

Here is that JS code that makes rain work.

```
var nbDrop = 120;

// function to generate a random number range.
function randRange( minNum, maxNum) {
  return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
}

// function to generate drops
function createRain() {

    for( i=1;i<nbDrop;i++) {
    var dropLeft = randRange(0,1280);
    var dropTop = randRange(-500,590);

    $('.rain').append('<div class="drop" id="drop'+i+'"></div>');
    $('#drop'+i).css('left',dropLeft);
    $('#drop'+i).css('top',dropTop);
    }

}
createRain();
```

So further I have a series of if statements and I want to change nbDrop variable which controls a number of drops. I want only one condition to result in raining, while others should set it to 0 value.

```
  function displayAnswer(answer) {           

var fortuneText = document.getElementById('answer');

    if (chosenAnswer == 0){
nbDrop = 0; 
}

else if (chosenAnswer == 1){
nbDrop = 0; 
}

else if (chosenAnswer == 2){
nbDrop = 0; 
}

else if (chosenAnswer == 3){
nbDrop = 0; 

}

else if (chosenAnswer == 4){

nbDrop = 0; 

}


else if (chosenAnswer == 5){


var nbDrop = 120;

// function to generate a random number range.
function randRange( minNum, maxNum) {
  return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
}

// function to generate drops
function createRain() {

    for( i=1;i<nbDrop;i++) {
    var dropLeft = randRange(0,1280);
    var dropTop = randRange(-500,590);

    $('.rain').append('<div class="drop" id="drop'+i+'"></div>');
    $('#drop'+i).css('left',dropLeft);
    $('#drop'+i).css('top',dropTop);
    }

}

createRain();
}
}
```

A problem is that it only works once when the last if statement is true. But when other conditions are true, rain keeps going, so that variable doesn't change to 0 for some reason. It stays at 120.

Even though the button I use to click to change if statements condition has an even listener on it:

```
  <button id="button1" onclick="displayAnswer();"></button>
```

Is there any way to make that nbDrop variable change to zero for all other if conditions, except one which should have it set to 120?

Comment: Where do you call the `createRain()` function from? You can simplify your if/else structure quite a bit: `if (chosenAnswer == 5) { nbDrop = 120; } else { nbDrop = 0; }`.

Comment: Please read about variable hosting in javascript. That might help

Comment: I forgot to put it in example, I just added it though. I do have it in my code in the end.

Comment: once createRain is called, it creates rain. but there's no code which removes rain. I can almost assure you the value of nbDrop is 0 when non rain conditions are met

Comment: So I need to create another function that removes existing rain?

Comment: I did that nnnnnn and rain keeps on going anyway once it starts. Is there anyway to connect an event listener to it so it changes variable to 0 once a button is clicked? I get a feeling it just doesn't update.

Comment: It's a part of        var answersArrayed = ["Yes. So nothing happens", "No. Enjoy your consequences", "Ok, but that's something different", "My answer won't help you, deal with it!", "Your questions don't matter anymore", "Your questions make it rain again"];     var numberOfAnswers = answersArrayed.length;

        var chosenAnswer = getAnswerNumber(numberOfAnswers);

Comment: But it all works perfect, I have more things that change with if statement and they all work. Only that rain function doesn't want to set its variable to 0 once it's set to 120.

Comment: Also, please, use a case/switch, despite what you may think, it's faster http://jsperf.com/performance-of-assigning-variables-in-javascript

Comment: I actually use your version for the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: You should remove the "var" in condition == 5, as it is already declared.

```
else if (chosenAnswer == 5){
    // var nbDrop = 120;
    nbDrop = 120;
```

2: The commented method will not run when the nbDrop is 0 as `i` start on 1 and 1 can never be smaller than 0

```
function createRain() {
    // for( i=1;i<nbDrop;i++) {
    for( i=0;i<=nbDrop;i++) {      // need to be like this
```

3: You have the `}` sign in a wrong place. Change it like this (see the "added" and "remove" comments in the code) or the "createRain" only gets called when condition == 5 is met. If you indent your code like below you will easier see within which code block things is.

**Update** Added an exit part in the "createRain" function

```
function displayAnswer(answer) {           

    var fortuneText = document.getElementById('answer');

    if (chosenAnswer == 0){
        nbDrop = 0; 
    }

    else if (chosenAnswer == 1){
        nbDrop = 0; 
    }

    else if (chosenAnswer == 2){
        nbDrop = 0; 
    }

   else if (chosenAnswer == 3){
       nbDrop = 0;     
   }

   else if (chosenAnswer == 4){   
       nbDrop = 0;      
   }

   else if (chosenAnswer == 5){    
       nbDrop = 120;

   }    // added

   // function to generate a random number range.
   function randRange( minNum, maxNum) {
       return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
   }

   // function to generate drops
   function createRain() {

        if (nbDrop == 0) {
            // remove the drop element(s)
            $('.rain').children().remove();
            // exit the function
            return;
        }

       for( i=0;i<=nbDrop;i++) {
           var dropLeft = randRange(0,1280);
           var dropTop = randRange(-500,590);

           $('.rain').append('<div class="drop" id="drop'+i+'"></div>');
           $('#drop'+i).css('left',dropLeft);
           $('#drop'+i).css('top',dropTop);
       }    
   }

   createRain();

   //}    removed

}
```

And, as requested, here is the fully working web page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Magic 8 Ball</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="topmask"></div>
    <div id="mainframe">
        <div id="mainframe2">
            <section class="rain"></section>
            <div id="rocketdear"></div><div id="smokedear"></div><div id="launchsmokedear"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="bubble"></div>
        <div id="bubbleHugecat"></div><div id="bubbleHugecatrays"></div>
        <div class="sign">
            <p id="question"></p>
            <p id="answer"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="eight-ball">
            <button id="button1" onclick="javascript:shake();"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottommask"></div>

    <script>



        var nbDrop;

        function shake() {

            var answersArrayed = ["Yes. So nothing happens", "No. Enjoy your consequences", "Ok, but that's something different", "My answer won't help you, deal with it!", "Your questions don't matter anymore", "Your questions make it rain again"];

            // The question we asked
            var question = prompt("Ask you question...");
            var questionText = document.getElementById('question');
            questionText.innerHTML = question;

            // Number of possible answers
            var numberOfAnswers = answersArrayed.length;

            // Answers the 8 Ball can return


            // Answer returned by our 8 Ball
            var chosenAnswer = getAnswerNumber(numberOfAnswers);
            displayAnswer(chosenAnswer);




            // Returns a number based on the number of sides
            function getAnswerNumber(answerCount) {
                var number = getRandomInt(0, numberOfAnswers);
                return number;
            }

            // Returns a random integer between two numbers
            function getRandomInt(min, max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
            }


            // Show our answer in the document
            function displayAnswer(answer) {



            }


            // Access the DOM element we want to to change
            var fortuneText = document.getElementById('answer');

            if (chosenAnswer == 0) {
                document.getElementById("bubble").className = "bubbleStill";
                fortuneText.innerHTML = answersArrayed[0];

                document.getElementById("smokedear").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
                document.getElementById("launchsmokedear").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
                document.getElementById("rocketdear").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
                document.getElementById("bubble").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';

                document.getElementById("bubble").style.opacity = "0";
                document.getElementById("bubbleHugecat").style.opacity = "0";
                document.getElementById("bubbleHugecatrays").style.opacity = "0";
                document.getElementById("mainframe").style.backgroundImage = "url('desert23.svg')";
                document.getElementById("smokedear").className = "smokestill";
                document.getElementById("launchsmokedear").className = "launchsmokestill";
                document.getElementById("rocketdear").className = "rocketstill";

                nbDrop = 0;

            }

            else if (chosenAnswer == 1) {
                fortuneText.innerHTML = answersArrayed[1];

                document.getElementById("smokedear").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
                document.getElementById("launchsmokedear").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
                document.getElementById("rocketdear").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';

                document.getElementById("bubble").className = "bubbleExploading";
                document.getElementById("bubble").style.webkitAnimation = '';
                document.getElementById("bubble").style.opacity = "1";
                document.getElementById("bubbleHugecat").style.opacity = "0";
                document.getElementById("bubbleHugecatrays").style.opacity = "0";
                document.getElementById("mainframe").style.backgroundImage = "url('desert23.svg')";
                document.getElementById("smokedear").className = "smokestill";
                document.getElementById("launchsmokedear").className = "launchsmokestill";
                document.getElementById("rocketdear").className = "rocketstill";

                nbDrop = 0;
            }

            else if (chosenAnswer == 2) {
                fortuneText.innerHTML = answersArrayed[2];

                document.getElementById("smokedear").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
                document.getElementById("launchsmokedear").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
                document.getElementById("rocketdear").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
                document.getElementById("bubble").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
                document.getElementById("bubbleHugecatrays").style.opacity = "1";
                document.getElementById("bubbleHugecat").style.opacity = "1";
                document.getElementById("mainframe").style.backgroundImage = "url('desert23.svg')";
                document.getElementById("bubble").className = "bubbleStill";
                document.getElementById("bubble").style.opacity = "0";
                document.getElementById("smokedear").className = "smokestill";
                document.getElementById("launchsmokedear").className = "launchsmokestill";
                document.getElementById("rocketdear").className = "rocketstill";

                nbDrop = 0;
            }

            else if (chosenAnswer == 3) {


                document.getElementById("smokedear").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
                document.getElementById("launchsmokedear").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
                document.getElementById("rocketdear").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
                document.getElementById("bubble").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
                fortuneText.innerHTML = answersArrayed[3];
                document.getElementById("bubbleHugecat").style.opacity = "0";
                document.getElementById("bubbleHugecatrays").style.opacity = "0";
                document.getElementById("bubble").className = "bubbleStill";
                document.getElementById("bubble").style.opacity = "0";
                document.getElementById("mainframe").style.backgroundImage = "url('desert_night.svg')";
                document.getElementById("smokedear").className = "smokestill";
                document.getElementById("launchsmokedear").className = "launchsmokestill";
                document.getElementById("rocketdear").className = "rocketstill";

                nbDrop = 0;

            }

            else if (chosenAnswer == 4) {

                fortuneText.innerHTML = answersArrayed[4];
                document.getElementById("smokedear").style.opacity = "1";
                document.getElementById("launchsmokedear").style.opacity = "1";
                document.getElementById("rocketdear").style.opacity = "1";
                document.getElementById("smokedear").className = "smoke";
                document.getElementById("launchsmokedear").className = "launchsmoke";
                document.getElementById("rocketdear").className = "rocket";
                document.getElementById("smokedear").style.webkitAnimation = '';
                document.getElementById("launchsmokedear").style.webkitAnimation = '';
                document.getElementById("rocketdear").style.webkitAnimation = '';
                document.getElementById("bubble").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';

                document.getElementById("mainframe").style.backgroundImage = "url('desert23.svg')";
                document.getElementById("bubbleHugecat").style.opacity = "0";
                document.getElementById("bubbleHugecatrays").style.opacity = "0";
                document.getElementById("bubble").className = "bubbleStill";
                document.getElementById("bubble").style.opacity = "0";

                nbDrop = 0;
            }


            else {

                fortuneText.innerHTML = answersArrayed[5];

                document.getElementById("smokedear").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
                document.getElementById("launchsmokedear").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
                document.getElementById("rocketdear").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
                document.getElementById("bubble").style.webkitAnimation = 'none';
                document.getElementById("smokedear").className = "smokestill";
                document.getElementById("launchsmokedear").className = "launchsmokestill";
                document.getElementById("rocketdear").className = "rocketstill";



                document.getElementById("mainframe").style.backgroundImage = "url('desert_rain.svg')";
                document.getElementById("bubbleHugecat").style.opacity = "0";
                document.getElementById("bubbleHugecatrays").style.opacity = "0";
                document.getElementById("bubble").className = "bubbleStill";
                document.getElementById("bubble").style.opacity = "0";

                nbDrop = 120;

            }


            // function to generate a random number range.
            function randRange(minNum, maxNum) {
                return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
            }



            // function to generate drops
            function createRain() {

                if (nbDrop == 0) {
                    // remove the drop element(s)
                    $('.rain').children().remove();
                    // exit the function
                    return;
                }

                for (i = 0; i <= nbDrop; i++) {

                    var dropLeft = randRange(0, 1280);
                    var dropTop = randRange(-500, 590);

                    $('.rain').append('<div class="drop" id="drop' + i + '"></div>');
                    $('#drop' + i).css('left', dropLeft);
                    $('#drop' + i).css('top', dropTop);

                }

            }
            createRain();

        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed it to var nbDrop = 0;


// function to generate a random number range.
function randRange( minNum, maxNum) {
  return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
}



// function to generate drops
function createRain(nbDrop) {
    for( i=0;i<=nbDrop;i++) {
 var dropLeft = randRange(0,1280);
 var dropTop = randRange(-500,590);

 $('.rain').append('<div class="drop" id="drop'+i+'"></div>');
 $('#drop'+i).css('left',dropLeft);
 $('#drop'+i).css('top',dropTop);
 }





}

Comment: and ran                 createRain(0); and                 createRain(120); when needed. Didn't change anything. When it starts raining, it keeps doing it anyway even when conditions change it to 0.

Comment: I seem to fix all of that and it's still doing its thing... I uploaded it to github maybe you could take a look at the full version of it.  https://github.com/stmalk/stmalk.github.io/blob/master/3/index.html

Comment: it's totally random, just push that button several times without even filling it

Comment: 1. End tag for this div is missing `<div id="mainframe">` ... 2. End tag for this div is missing `<div id="eight-ball">` ... 3. this line is still wrong `for (i = 1; i <= nbDrop; i++) {`, should be `for (i = 0; i <= nbDrop; i++) {`

Comment: I fixed the code, but it doesn't change a problem though. I use Chrome, it should work, just click through it several times, it's 6 random variants.

Comment: I wish I knew more jQuery at this point it seems so simple, just stopping the function from working.